# include php não funciona

Tags: php, include

Tenho a seguinte arvore de diretórios:

```
.var
..|--www
......|--site
..........|--index.php
..........|--all
..............|--controller
..................|--conexao.php (classe)
..............|--model
..................|--bo
..................|--vo
..................|--dao
.....................|--prioridade_dao.php (classe)
```

Beleza bem extenso, o problema é o seguinte:
Inclui a classe prioridade_dao.php dentro de index.php (até ai tudo bem) se eu "NÃO" colocar nenhum include na prioridade_dao.php aparecem as coisas ao visualizar a pagina, agora se eu colocar qualquer include na classe prioridade_dao.php não aparece mais nada. Já tentei:

```
include ('../../controller/conexao.php');
include '../../controller/conexao.php';
include ("../../controller/conexao.php");
include "../../controller/conexao.php";
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/all/controller/conexao.php";
```

Segue classe prioridade_dao.php:

```
<?php
Class PrioridadeDao{
    error_reporting(-1); 
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/all/controller/conexao.php";
    $conexao = new Conexao();       

    public function __construct(){

    }

    public function teste(){
        echo "Chega aqui sim";
    }


    public function selectAll(){
        echo "<br />CHEGA AQUI?";

        if(!$conexao->conecta()){
            exit;
        } else {
            $result = pg_query($conexao->conecta(), "SELECT * FROM prioridade");
            while ($consulta = @pg_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $consulta['nivel']." ".$consulta['nome'];
            }
            $conexaoObj->encerra($conexao->conecta());
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Já tentei também com require, tudo sem sucesso. Fiz um teste chamando por include direto a `conexao.php` na `index.php` e consegui fazer. Estou usando métodos `__construct()` vazios nas classes, pode ser isso? Enfim já pesquisei em um monte de lugares, testei muitas coisas e nada :( se puderem me ajudar ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Afinal você que incluir qual arquivo dentro de qual arquivo?

Comment: Mostre o código do prioridade_dao.php

Comment: habilita os erros no php.ini e coloca aqui o erro

Comment: Eu quero incluir o conexao.php dentro do prioridade_dao.php

Comment: Coloca isto no inicio do ficheiro prioridade_dao.php: `error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`

Comment: Use Path absoluto, ao invés de Path relativo.

Comment: @LuanGabrieldaCostaRodrigue Editei minha resposta.

Comment: Coloque o include dentro de algum método, ou fora da classe

Comment: Fabio alterei a publicação. O $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] imprime isso exatamente:
/var/www/ticketdbx/public_html bem onde eu precisava.

Comment: @LuanGabrieldaCostaRodrigue para notificar o usuário, coloque um @ na frente do nome dele. E use o espaço da resposta apenas para responder perguntas. Converti seu comentário para cá :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque seu include fora da classe, assim:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1); 
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

require_once __DIR__."{$ds}..{$ds}..{$ds}controller{$ds}conexao.php";

Class PrioridadeDao{

    private $conexao;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->conexao =  = new Conexao();
    }

    public function teste(){
        echo "Chega aqui sim";
    }


    public function selectAll(){
        echo "<br />CHEGA AQUI?";

        if(!$conexao->conecta()){
            exit;
        } else {
            $result = pg_query($conexao->conecta(), "SELECT * FROM prioridade");
            while ($consulta = @pg_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $consulta['nivel']." ".$consulta['nome'];
            }
            $conexaoObj->encerra($conexao->conecta());
        }
    }
}
```

O escopo de uma classe deve ser pra criar propriedades (variáveis de contexto) e métodos (funções da classe). Requisições de classes que serão utilizadas pela classe em questão deve ser inseridas antes da declaração da classe.

Comment: Opa dessa forma os erros começaram a aparecer e algo já foi adiante. Agora eis que me surge outro problema, não consigo instanciar a classe conexao.php se eu instancio ela no construtor mais adiante ocorre erro no metodo, e se eu instancio fora do contrutor simplesmente nao aparece nada na pagina.

Comment: Fiz um update @LuanGabrieldaCostaRodrigue

Comment: @Fabio Cardoso, consegui fazer funcionar seguindo as dicas que o KaduAmaral forneceu. Usando include fora da classe e instanciando no método construtor. Mesmo assim gostaria de agradecer a todos que disponibilizaram seu tempo e vontade para me ajudar. Grato a todos.

Comment: @LuanGabrieldaCostaRodrigue eu só forneci detalhes para correção do problema atual, para evitar esses tipos de problema o melhor a se fazer é seguir padrões. Dê uma boa estudada em padrões em MVC e procure desenvolver conforme a [resposta do Mandrake](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/74339/8493). Abraços e sucesso.

Answer (score 3):

Correto em se trabalhar com OPP, é definir seus arquivos de configurações em uma pasta chamada `Config`, o diretório `Controller`, como o próprio nome já diz é para enviar e receber comandos para a view ou model. E seu arquivo de conexão está no lugar totalmente errado.

Includes com `paths` relativos são problemáticos

```
require_once '../../controller/conexao.php'
```

Use paths absolutos, ou seja inclua o caminho completo do arquivo, uma forma simples de se fazer isso, é definir este valor em uma constante e ser chamada por um `Bootstrap`.

```
define('CONFIG', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)). 'Config'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

(PHP 5 => v5.3)

```
define('CONFIG', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)). 'Config'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Depois só incluir o arquivo onde deseja.

```
require_once CONFIG . 'conexao.php';
```

Comment: Olá Mandrake, valeu pela dica, mas para quem não conhece plenamente  a linguagem (estou iniciando em PHP) sua dica fica voando no ar, não sei como se utiliza a função define nem como fazer essa chamada de constante com bootstrap, ai no meu caso não ajuda em nada :( mas valeu mesmo assim.

Comment: Coloque esta constante na index, e de um echo, quando achar o caminho do script, faça o required na classe, a cada [dirname](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.dirname.php) aplicado, vai recuar um diretório da raiz, desta forma você acha o caminho do script, saiba mais no [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.dirname.php). e constante é básico da linguagem ;)

Answer (score 0):

Se quer incluir `conexao.php` dentro de `prioridade_dao.php` seria desta forma:

```
require_once '../../controller/conexao.php';
```

*Se não conseguir incluir vai dar erro e será exposto o erro.

O erro no seu código é que você esta fazendo a inclusão dentro da função teste porem o mesmo não é chamado logo não há inclusão (tente ter uma arquitetura mais simples pois minimiza as chances de sair do controle). faça a inclusão direta logo abaixo do `<?php` da forma que fiz acima.

Comment: @LuanGabrieldaCostaRodrigue se der erro poste aqui.

Comment: Eu fiz isso, a saida que eu coloquei dentro da função era para ver qual seria o diretorio impresso para ver se ele estaria correto.

Comment: @LuanGabrieldaCostaRodrigue do jeito que fiz o que foi reportado?

Comment: Consegui resolver fazendo da forma como o kadu apresentou utilizando o include fora da classe.